# electron url scheme "open-url" event

Tags: node.js, electron, nwjs

I did the following in my `index.js`;

```
electron.remote.app.on("open-url", function(event, url) {
  console.log("Open URL: " + url);
});
```

This gets triggered in Mac OS, but not in Windows. Is there another event or a different way to do it in windows?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a mac-only feature.
The closest alternative is [app.makeSingleInstance(callback)](http://electron.atom.io/docs/all/#appmakesingleinstancecallback).

You can arrange for your app to be launched with the url as argument: myApp my-scheme://stuff

Then `callback` is called with the url in whichever app process was launched first.

Answer (score 18):

[From mine similar Q/A at SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43912119/open-app-and-pass-parameters-with-deep-linking-using-electron-macos):
It's about opening app and pass parameters with deep linking using Electron for both platforms (macOS/win32).

---

> Minimal electron project with deep linking capabilities in macOS/win32 platforms (Single Instance Application) ['electron-deep-linking-mac-win' on GitHub](https://github.com/oikonomopo/electron-deep-linking-mac-win).

---

`package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "electron-deeplinking-macos-win32",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "Minimal Electron application with deep inking (macOS/win32)",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron .",
    "pack": "build --dir",
    "dist": "build"
  },
  "repository": "https://github.com/oikonomopo/electron-deep-linking-osx",
  "author": "oikonomopo",
  "license": "CC0-1.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "1.6.6",
    "electron-builder": "17.1.2"
  },
  "build": {
    "appId": "oikonomopo.electron-deeplinking-macos-win32",
    "protocols": {
      "name": "electron-deep-linking",
      "schemes": ["myapp"]
    },
    "mac": {
      "category": "public.app-category.Reference"
    },
    "win": {
    }
  }
}
```

---

`main.js`:

```
const {app, BrowserWindow} = require('electron')
// Module with utilities for working with file and directory paths.
const path = require('path')
// Module with utilities for URL resolution and parsing.
const url = require('url')

// Keep a global reference of the window object, if you don't, the window will
// be closed automatically when the JavaScript object is garbage collected.
let mainWindow

// Deep linked url
let deeplinkingUrl

// Force Single Instance Application
const shouldQuit = app.makeSingleInstance((argv, workingDirectory) => {
  // Someone tried to run a second instance, we should focus our window.

  // Protocol handler for win32
  // argv: An array of the second instance’s (command line / deep linked) arguments
  if (process.platform == 'win32') {
    // Keep only command line / deep linked arguments
    deeplinkingUrl = argv.slice(1)
  }
  logEverywhere("app.makeSingleInstance# " + deeplinkingUrl)

  if (mainWindow) {
    if (mainWindow.isMinimized()) mainWindow.restore()
        mainWindow.focus()
  }
})
if (shouldQuit) {
    app.quit()
    return
}

function createWindow () {
  // Create the browser window.
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({width: 800, height: 600})

  // and load the index.html of the app.
  mainWindow.loadURL(url.format({
    pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'),
    protocol: 'file:',
    slashes: true
  }))

  // Open the DevTools.
  mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools()

  // Protocol handler for win32
  if (process.platform == 'win32') {
    // Keep only command line / deep linked arguments
    deeplinkingUrl = process.argv.slice(1)
  }
  logEverywhere("createWindow# " + deeplinkingUrl)

  // Emitted when the window is closed.
  mainWindow.on('closed', function () {
    // Dereference the window object, usually you would store windows
    // in an array if your app supports multi windows, this is the time
    // when you should delete the corresponding element.
    mainWindow = null
  })
}

// This method will be called when Electron has finished
// initialization and is ready to create browser windows.
// Some APIs can only be used after this event occurs.
app.on('ready', createWindow)

// Quit when all windows are closed.
app.on('window-all-closed', function () {
  // On OS X it is common for applications and their menu bar
  // to stay active until the user quits explicitly with Cmd + Q
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit()
  }
})

app.on('activate', function () {
  // On OS X it's common to re-create a window in the app when the
  // dock icon is clicked and there are no other windows open.
  if (mainWindow === null) {
    createWindow()
  }
})

// Define custom protocol handler. Deep linking works on packaged versions of the application!
app.setAsDefaultProtocolClient('myapp')

// Protocol handler for osx
app.on('open-url', function (event, url) {
  event.preventDefault()
  deeplinkingUrl = url
  logEverywhere("open-url# " + deeplinkingUrl)
})

// Log both at dev console and at running node console instance
function logEverywhere(s) {
    console.log(s)
    if (mainWindow && mainWindow.webContents) {
        mainWindow.webContents.executeJavaScript(`console.log("${s}")`)
    }
}
```

main.js code description:

- At `let deeplinkingUrl` we keep the provided url.
- At macOS platform this is captured at [`'open-url'` event](https://electron.atom.io/docs/api/app/#event-open-url-macos), we set it with `deeplinkingUrl = url`! (See `// Protocol handler for osx`)
- At win32 platform this is saved at [`process.argv`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_argv) together with other arguments. To get only the provided url, `deeplinkingUrl = argv.slice(1)`.  (See `// Protocol handler for win32`)
- As [@Aurélien Nicolas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38458857/electron-url-scheme-open-url-event#answer-39297057) mentions, at [`app.makeSingleInstance` method](https://electron.atom.io/docs/api/app/#appmakesingleinstancecallback) we check in which platform we are and we set `deeplinkingUrl` accordingly! If we are at win32 platform, the url is located at `argv` variable from callback, else at macOS should have already been set at `'open-url'` event! (See `// Force Single Instance Application`)

Comment: It is not working in windows for me. Does this only work if we install app on the platform ? OR I can test it in dev mode somehow ?

Comment: @MuhammadYawarAli, if i remember correctly, in order to register a protocol handler for your app, you need to make the installer that will register it. (using electron-builder project to package our app) So yes you should first install the app.

Comment: ok i’ll try building an installer, but it did work for mac os even in dev mode.

Comment: I tested deep link in mac production build, when app is closed I am not getting anything in `open-url` event but app opens up on deep link though. If app is minimised OR unfocused everything works fine.