# Electron JS - Deep Linking - Example of how to use deep linking

Tags: javascript, electron

In Electron JS, I created an app for Windows and registered my own protocol for deep linking. The app properly opens when clicking on my link `ludo://play?level=1234`. No problem there. However I don't know how to retrieve the deep link inside of my app. The docs for [app.setAsDefaultProtocolClient](http://electron.atom.io/docs/all/#appsetasdefaultprotocolclientprotocol-path-args-macos-windows) mention this sentence:

`The whole link, including protocol, will be passed to your application as a parameter.`

Can anyone tell me how to retrieve that? Because it is not in `process.argv` nor is it in `process.execPath` or `process.execArgv`.

Could it be passed in a callback when the app starts? Any help on this would be great.

Comment: Take a look at my answer in another SO question: [Pass URL scheme in a Single Instance Electron Application for Windows.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38458857/electron-url-scheme-open-url-event/43842895#43842895)

Comment: Anyone did it for ubuntu electon app? i have successfully done it for windows and mac

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On macOS you need to listen to the [`app.open-url` event](http://electron.atom.io/docs/api/app/#event-open-url-macos), while on Windows the url should be available in `process.argv` (in the main process).

Comment: Ah yes, Chromium is multi-process. I was looking in the browser window process.argv (`app.js`) but in fact, you have to do it in the main process (`background.js`). Thanks!

Comment: @MartinDrapeau:
stuck to same problem but not able to get how to do this,can you please provide a sample code for this

Comment: what about ubuntu?